# Is height of a non-binary tree logarithmic?

Tags: tree

If I have a tree each of whose nodes can have a variable number of children, then is the height of the tree logarithmic?

For example, in a binary tree of n elements, height is log(n).

Comment: Well, no because a chain is a tree with one child and its height is n.

Comment: @sashkello: that's actually log(n) for that "tree". When we have a "tree" with only one-child-nodes, we have to use log1(n) to calculate the height... Which is actually the same as 1*n.

Comment: @HenrikHillestadLøvold You're right, I was thinking in terms of scaling rather than the formula.

Comment: @sashkello then you were right too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mushfiqur is correct -- the height of a non-binary tree may vary from *log(n)* to *n*. In the case where every node only has one child node, the height is *n*. A tree like that would actually look like a singly linked list datastructure.

On the other hand, in the case where every node except the leaf nodes has its maximum number of children, and where every subtree is equally high (or equally-1 high) we have a balanced tree. As long as a tree is balanced, its height will always be *log(n)*.

Keep in mind that *log(n)* isn't always just *log(n)*! When we talk about computer science, we usually talk about *log2(n)*, but when talking about an *m*'ary tree, we have to use *log m(n)* to get the actual height. E.g. a balanced tree where each node has three children has a *log3(n)* height.

Comment: Thanks! :) Yes, I do see what you all mean about the n to logm(n) variation. In fact your explanation made me understand the difference in the maximum and minimum possible heights of a d-ary tree. The maximum possible height would be d and the minimum possible height would be log(n) where base is d. (A d-ary tree is a tree each of whose nodes can have at the most d children.)

Comment: Exactly! Glad you understood it! Please mark the question as answered if you feel like it's been answered :)

Answer (score 1):

Not always.If it is balanced then it is log(n). Otherwise the height can vary from log(n) to n.

Answer (score 0):

Thats right this is not always true and varies from log(n) to n depending on the fact that the tree is balanced or not. 
For a partially complete and complete binary tree is will be equal to log(n) but for a tree with chains of Nodes it will be equal to O(n).

```
For example for  complete binary tree

       1
      /  \
    2     3
   / \    /\
 4    5  6  7
```

Height of the tree will be log(n)

But for a chain of nodes

```
          1
         /
        2
       /
      3
     /
    4
```

Height  of the tree is O(n)